# Android soft input keypad pushes buttons up which overlap other views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a button aligned to the bottom of my Relative Layout which I want to be pushed up when soft keypad is shown, but I don't want it to overlap other views, any hints?

#### I have the following layout(XML):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_app" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="02dp"
        android:background="@drawable/options_bg" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="03dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="03dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="Date"
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_calendar"
        android:textColor="#FFBF00" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopwrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPWRSTUVWXYZ. "
        android:ems="6"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:textColor="#002f44" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:padding="03dp"
        android:textColor="#610B0B" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_style"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Self"
            android:textColor="#002f44" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Other"
            android:textColor="#002f44" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button01"
        android:text="Type "
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopwrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPWRSTUVWXYZ. "
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:ems="8"
        android:hint="Friends Name"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2.3dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_exit"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="03dp"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_down" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:textColor="#002f44"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### In the manifest:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

below is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use `alignParentBottom=true` for your button. Try to construct the layout without setting this parameter to true.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_addreminder"
    android:text="Next"
    android:textColor="#002f44"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**EDIT**

As the documentation says:

**adjustResize** `The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.`

**adjustPan**   `The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.`

I suggest you to rethink the design, and use adjustPan instead of adjustResize.

But if your next button is meant to be used to navigate through your edit texts than take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AimeOptions)

Comment: I dont think the button will be pushed if its not aligned to the parent. Let me try my hands on that.

Comment: Nah - not working. I want my button to be pushed up, but I dont want it to overlap other views once it gets pushed.

Comment: Thanks, it did help. Should've refactored my root view to LinearLayout, and put above my last bottom button new View with set layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1" to force the button go to the very bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"`

Comment: It gives me the Same behavior.